# Are all incomparable elements in a set considered both maximal and minimal?

Tags: order-theory

Say I have a set that has mixed comparable and incomparable elements.

$$S_C = \{ 1, 2, 3 \}$$

$$S_I = \{, \}$$

$$...$$

$$ S_M = S_C \cup S_I \cup ... $$

$$ where $$

$$S_J \in S_I || S_M\setminus S_j $$

By convention, are all elements of $S_J$ said to be both maximal and minimal on the set $S_M$?

Comment: It’s not a “convention”! An element $a$ is minimal (resp. maximal) for a partial order $\leq$ if there is no $b \neq a$ such that $b \leq a$ (resp. $b \geq a$). In particular, if $a$ is comparable with nothing else, $a$ is indeed both maximal and minimal. Note also that “a comparable element” doesn’t make sense – a *pair* of elements is comparable.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know what to say for "comparable element." Is it better to say something like "has mixed elements both comparable and incomparable over itself."

Comment: Your last line "$\forall S_j:S_j \in S_I || S_n\setminus S_j$" doesn't make much sense. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Each element $S_j$ in $S_I$ is not comparable to any element in $S_n$ excluding itself.